# Как создать WYSIWYG редактор в WordPress с использованием Customization API?

Tags: php, wordpress

Не удается создать WYSIWYG редактор текста на странице кастомизации темы. Может кто сталкивался?

Comment: А как выглядят ваши попытки создать его? Приведите код. На мой взгляд ничего сложного нету, возможно потому что я не знаю ситуацию.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$content = '';
$editor_id = 'mycustomeditor';

wp_editor( $content, $editor_id );

?>
```

[параметры](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor#Parameters)  функции